# How to pass a parameter from one tab to another and change the tab with a button?

Tags: java, android

I explain. I have a tabhost with 2 tab one has a ListView with a context menu. The menu has 2 options. The one that interests me is to edit. Pressing edit should take me to the other tab and allow me to edit the data.

For this, my idea is to take the value of the position with a Listenerlongclic and pass that position to the ArrayList to take out the object and set each of the object's getters in their corresponding TextLayout. I don't know if I explain myself. I leave the code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ArrayList datos = new ArrayList();
private ListView listCuadros;
private AdaptadorCuadros adaptador;
private Context contexto;
private int i=0;
private EditText titulo;
private EditText autor;
private EditText estilo;
private EditText precio;
private EditText fecha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TabHost tabs = findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Lista del museo");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("mitab2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Editor");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(0);
    contexto = this;
    datos.add(new Cuadros("La Mona Lisa", "Leonardo da Vinci", "Renacentista", "$713.000.000", "1503"));
    datos.add(new Cuadros("El grito", "Munch", "Expresionismo", "$119.900.000", "1893"));
    datos.add(new Cuadros("La persistencia de la memoria", "Dalí ", "Surrealismo", "$400.000.000", "1931"));
    datos.add(new Cuadros("El nacimiento de Venus", "Sandro Botticelli", "Gotico", "Desconocido", "1482"));
    datos.add(new Cuadros("Guernica", "Pablo Picasso", "Cubismo", "€300.000.000", "1937"));
    datos.add(new Cuadros("Los jugadores de cartas", "Paul Cézanne", "Posimpresionismo", "€191.000.000", "1890"));
    adaptador = new AdaptadorCuadros(this, datos);
    titulo = findViewById((R.id.titulo));
    autor = findViewById((R.id.autor));
    estilo = findViewById(R.id.estilo);
    precio = findViewById(R.id.precio);
    fecha = findViewById(R.id.fecha);
    listCuadros = findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listCuadros.setAdapter(adaptador);
    registerForContextMenu(listCuadros);
    listCuadros.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            i = position;
            return false;
        }
});
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mimenu, menu);
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.mi1:
            editar();
            return true;
        case R.id.mi2:
            borrar();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void editar() {

}

private void borrar() {
    String mensaje = "Va a borrar uno de los cuadros, esta seguro?";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(contexto);
    builder.setTitle("Confirmacion");
    builder.setMessage(mensaje);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.i("Dialogos", "Confirmacion Cancelada.");
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            Log.i("Dialogos", "Confirmacion Aceptada.");
             datos.remove(i);
                adaptador.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: You could also post your question over on https://es.stackoverflow.com or https://pt.stackoverflow.com if you prefer receiving help in your own language

Comment: I'm sorry, copy the wrong side: P

Comment: @Nicolas is to have more answers since android is not easy to get answers

Answer (score 0):

a) If you are familiar with `MVVM`, You can pass via `ViewModel`

b) You can save and use your data in `SharedPreferences`. How? Example:

Create public class, name it `SaveSharedPreference`.

```
public class SaveSharedPreference {
   static final String USER_NAME = "user_name";

   static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

   static SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences(Context ctx) {
        if (sharedPreferences == null) sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
        return sharedPreferences;
   }


   public static void setUserName(Context ctx, String user_name) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
        editor.putString(USER_NAME, user_name);
        editor.apply();
   }

   public static String getUserName(Context context) {
        if (null != getSharedPreferences(context).getString(USER_NAME, ""))
            return getSharedPreferences(context).getString(USER_NAME, "");
        else
            return "";
   }
}
```

Save and use your data which you pass in your Activity (or Fragment):

```java
String sValue = "Saving value";
SaveSharedPreference.setUserName(this, sValue);
```

```java
String tmp = SaveSharedPreference.getUserName(this);
```